# "next-auth/react" module not found when making custom email sign in page in next-auth

Tags: npm, next.js, yarnpkg, next-auth

I'm making a NextJs application with next-auth for the authentication part.
Email Sign In is successfully implemented using next-auth's own default pages.

But now I would like to have a custom sign in page. I followed the [documentation](https://next-auth.js.org/configuration/pages) for this, and added
`pages: { signIn: '/auth/signin' }` in my [...nextauth].js file. Then, I added the given [Email Sign In code](https://next-auth.js.org/configuration/pages#email-sign-in) in *pages/auth/signin.js*.
But upon running `yarn dev`, I get this module not found error:

```
error - ./pages/api/auth/signin.js:1:0
Module not found: Package path ./react is not exported from package C:\...\node_modules\next-auth (see exports field in C:\...\node_modules\next-auth\package.json)
> 1 | import { getCsrfToken } from "next-auth/react"
  2 | 
  3 | export default function SignIn({ csrfToken }) {
  4 |   return (

Import trace for requested module:

https://nextjs.org/docs/messages/module-not-found
```

And I couldn't find any module named 'next-auth/react' in npm or yarn websites.
Even in next-auth folder in node_modules, there is no 'react' named file...

How can I solve this? And am I doing anything wrong here?

Answer (score 23, accepted):

I faced the same issue and realised the docs are for **v4** where `next-auth/react` is used.

You are probably on **v3** where `next-auth/client` is used instead.

To use the beta version, do:

```sh
➜ npm i next-auth@beta
```

Answer (score 6):

You can now run `npm install next-auth` or `yarn add next-auth`. This will update the version of next-auth to version 4 in which you import SessionProvider as follows (within _app.tsx) :

`import { SessionProvider } from "next-auth/react"`

Answer (score 5):

I think it should be imported from `client` and **not** react

try this : `import { getCsrfToken } from "next-auth/client"`

Also,

(just sharing an alternate solution), you need not define the custom pages in next auth. you can have your own login page and there just call next-auth's `signin` method, by passing the type like `email` or `google`.

and if email, then pass the email as well. eg:

```js
const handleSubmit = (event) => {
    event.preventDefault();
    signIn("email", { email, callbackUrl: `${process.env.VERCEL_URL}/` });
};
```

Comment: Yes, with `next-auth/client` the error isn't showing up and Thanks for the alternate solution. It seems better.

Answer (score 2):

[Its due to Next-Auth v4 Upgrades, check](https://next-auth.js.org/getting-started/upgrade-v4)
https://next-auth.js.org/getting-started/upgrade-v4

Contained breaking changes, read to get better clarity.

Answer (score 1):

I was facing this issue. I was using the **"next-auth": "^4.18.7"** version. my node version was **14.0.0**. when I update this version to **18.12.1** then the issue is resolved.

Answer (score 0):

I find it best to solve this problem by adding this line to exports field of the 'project/directoy/node_modules/next-auth/package.json' file, hope it helps.

"./providers/credentials": "./providers/credentials.js"[image]

(Thanks to Mojtaba-NikAeen's GitHub answer: https://github.com/nextauthjs/next-auth/discussions/3467#discussioncomment-1891801)