# How to resolve next-auth/client module not found issue on Nextjs

Tags: reactjs, next.js, next-auth

I am working on a nextjs project using Prisma and GitHub auth, after running `npm run dev` project fail to compile as shown in the image below;

[image: Failed to compile]

How do I resolve this issue?

package.json below

```js
{
  "name": "hello-next",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "",
  "scripts": {
    "dev": "next",
    "build": "next build",
    "start": "next start"
  },
  "keywords": [],
  "author": "",
  "license": "MIT",
  "dependencies": {
    "@prisma/client": "^3.6.0",
    "next": "^12.0.7",
    "next-auth": "^4.0.5",
    "react": "16.14.0",
    "react-dom": "16.14.0",
    "react-markdown": "5.0.2"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@types/next-auth": "3.1.14",
    "@types/node": "14.14.6",
    "@types/react": "16.9.56",
    "prisma": "^3.6.0",
    "typescript": "4.5.4"
  }
}
```

Comment: Does this answer your question: ["next-auth/react" module not found when making custom email sign in page in next-auth](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69088378/next-auth-react-module-not-found-when-making-custom-email-sign-in-page-in-next)? You should use `next-auth/react`  on `next-auth` v4.

Answer (score 13):

next-auth/client has been [renamed](https://next-auth.js.org/getting-started/upgrade-v4#next-authreact)

Comment: Spoiler, to: next-auth/react. (atm)